# Generate XML comments from regular comments

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, xml-comments

We are in the process of upgrading a large amount of .Net code that was created prior to the advent of XML comments.

This code contains a lot of comments that are either directly above the applicable code member:

```
' This property returns true if ...
Public ReadOnly Property ReturnTrueIf As Boolean
```

or in the "old school" format that I think was used by automatic documentation compilers like sandcastle:

```
'===================================================
' Class Description:
'   Description of this class
'
' Remarks:
'   Some remarks about this class.
'
Public Class SomeClass
```

There is a lot of valuable information encapsulated in these comments that we would like to expose through XML commenting.

However, we have only been able to convert these comments manually by first inserting the xml comment template (typing ''' directly above the member), then adding the XML comment indicators (''') before the old comments and manually moving them into the new XML block. This is obviously very inefficient.

Unfortunately we can't just use a standard block of XML comment template code embedded in a macro since we want to pickup the method parameters, return values, etc.

Are there any known addins or functionality baked into VS2012 that we are overlooking?

Comment: _prior to the advent of XML comments_ -- out of curiosity, when were they introduced?  I thought they were always there.

Comment: Early in the 2000s (.net 1.0/1, VS2002/3). Formal XML comments were not introduced in VB.Net until VS2005.

Answer (score 0):

(AFAIK) there is nothing like it embedded in any version of VS. There could *possibly* be something in Resharper, Coderush or Justcode.
FWIW: I'd go for writing a simple app with Regex magic in it.